# JQuery Select element by name class and name

Tags: jquery, select

I have this html:

```
<input type="text" class="SePresu" name="Hola">
```

as I select it in jquery by class type and name.

Regards

Comment: Did you have a look at all the available selectors? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
$("[name=Hola]");
```

or to improve performance:

```
$(".SePresu[name=Hola]");
```

the more specific you are in your selectors, the better.

more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Update in response to comment.

You can then also filter by type text:

```
$(".SePresu[name=Hola] :text");
```

Anyway, even if youo have multiple elements with the same class, you would be already filtering by name, so it would select the input text and not the password.

IF you had more than one element with the same class AND name, then you would need to be more specific, unless of course yoy wanted to select ALL those elements.

Comment: and I can also tell you in the condition that it is the type = text because I have other input with the same class but type password

Answer (score 3):

Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for classname and [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for name attribute

```
$('.SePresu[name="Hola"]').fadeIn();
```

Comment: and I can also tell you in the condition that it is the type = text because I have other input with the same class but type password

Comment: @RonalVasquez but the name is different right... then this is enough